# update table and add missing columns - matlab

Tags: matlab

```
t1 = struct2table(struct('a',1, 'b',2, 'c',3));
t2 = struct2table(struct('a',NaN, 'c',4, 'd',5));

t1 =
    a    b    c
    _    _    _
    1    2    3

t2 =
     a     c    d
    ___    _    _
    NaN    4    5
```

I'd like to update `t1` with the values from `t2` on the common columns, and also add the unique `t2` columns to `t1`.

I tried:

```
>> join(t1,t2, 'Keys',{'a','c'})
Error using tabular/join (line 172)
The key variables cannot contain any missing values.

>> outerjoin(t1,t2, 'Keys',{'a','c'}, 'Merge',1)

ans =

  2×4 table

     a      b     c     d 
    ___    ___    _    ___

      1      2    3    NaN
    NaN    NaN    4      5
```

Desired output:

```
     a      b     c     d 
    ___    ___    _    ___

    NaN      2    4     5
```

Comment: 3 and 4 are different numbers. Why do you want to merge those two rows? What is the rule you're following here? Or do you always have only one row in each table? Tables are designed to handle many rows, if you have only one row, you might want to use a struct instead.

Comment: The rule is (1) replace `t1` values with `t2` values on common columns with `t2` (in my example, `a`, `b` and `c`) and (2) add the unique columns of `t2` to `t1` (in my example, `d`)

Comment: But how do you match rows? `outerjoin(..., 'Keys',{'a','c'}` means you want to match rows if the values in the `a` and `c`  columns matches, but this is obviously not your goal. Your example has only one row, so it's hard to understand what the row matching rule is. Do you ever have more than one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is

> Update `t1` with the values from `t2` on the common columns, and also add the unique `t2` columns to `t1`.

Which sounds equivalent to

> Use all columns from `t2`, and the columns from `t1` which are not present in `t2`

That's easier to parse into code, since you can do

```
t1 = struct2table(struct('a',1, 'b',2, 'c',3));
t2 = struct2table(struct('a',NaN, 'c',4, 'd',5));

t1Vars = t1.Properties.VariableNames;
t2Vars = t2.Properties.VariableNames;
t3 = [t1( :, ~ismember(t1Vars, t2Vars)), t2];
```

Which gives

```
t3 =
  1×4 table
    b     a     c    d
    _    ___    _    _

    2    NaN    4    5
```

The column order doesn't exactly match your "desired output", which seems like you want to prioritise the variables from `t1` first, you can do this with

```
t3 = t3( :, [t1Vars, setdiff(t2Vars,t1Vars,'stable')] );
```

Which gives the desired output

```
t3 =
  1×4 table
     a     b    c    d
    ___    _    _    _

    NaN    2    4    5
```